# Bootstrap Modal -> Swipe left / right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a jQuery Plugin that opens a Overlay with an Image and Custom HTML on the Bottom like the Facebook-Overlay when I click on a Image in my Timeline.

Under the Image I want to show comments and so on. I thought i could use maybe the bootstrap modal but how can I modify it that I can swipe left / right for next / previous item?

Comment: Maybe you can use jquery accordion to achieve this.

Comment: Use any jQuery image slider plugin, like *carousel*

Answer (score 0):

To swipe use library - jQuery.min.js, jquery.mobile.min.js.

Within modal put a carousel.
Code to swipe carousel is

```
jQuery(".carousel").swiperight(function() {
  jQuery(this).carousel('prev');
});
jQuery(".carousel").swipeleft(function() {
  jQuery(this).carousel('next');
});
```

In carousel item you can design how you wish.